# Is it possible in Google Sheets to generate an email address based on data from two different cells?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a database of individuals in a company in Google Sheets. I'm collecting the persons email address, first name, last name all in different columns. The email addresses for all these people always use the same syntax, first.last@company.com.

Is it possible to create a function in Google Sheets that will auto generate the email address based on data entered in the "First name" and "Last name" columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=CONCATENATE(A1,".",B1,"@company.com")` will do exactly what you want:

[image: sheets email concatenate]

It may not be the prettiest answer, but you can also combine a few concat() functions together to get `=CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(A1,"."),B1),"@company.com")` to do this:

[image: sheets email concat]

Comment: Just click the little blue square at the bottom right of that field and drag down.

Comment: "=CONCATENATE(A1,".",B1,"@company.com")" works great, thank you.

Comment: Will do, just as soon as I have the reputation. Your response was a big help!